# Regex to match a pattern but not include another pattern

Tags: regex

I'd like a regex to match thank-you but exclude it when the string contains the word removals. 
So contact-thank-you should return a positive but removals/contact-thank-you should return a negative

I don't know much about regex and found a couple of posts refering to negative lookaheads. The best i could come up with was

(?!(?:removals)).*thank-you

which is clearly rubbish. Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try `^(?!.*removals).*thank-you.*`. It depends on what the environment is, if you need the whole string match or not. Please show your code to help you better and quicker. Are the strings multiline, BTW? `.` in most regex flavors does not match line break characters.

Comment: Note you may use just `string.contains` like methods.

Comment: What language/tools are you using? For example, if this in `grep` then you can do: `grep 'thank-you' <file> | grep -v removals`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor and Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ideally want in this case is a negative lookbehind, since you're looking "behind" (to the left) of the word you're matching to make sure something's not there.

A complication here is that many regex engines don't permit variable-width negative-lookbehinds.

But if you can anchor to the start of the string you want to match somehow, then you can use lookahead from that anchor, instead.

```
(?:\s|^)((?!removals)\S)+thank-you(?:\s|$)

bananas/fred-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/fred-no-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/thank-you-with-words-after - no match.
removals/fred-thank-you - no match.
non-removals/fred-thank-you - no match.
bananas/removals-thank-you - no match.
bananas/thank-you-supremovalsale - no match.
bananas/fred-sorry - no match.
```

I am presuming that the characters permitted in the string are "anything but whitespace".

So it starts out by looking for either the beginning of the string, or some whitespace; then any number of non-whitespace \S characters that aren't the beginning of the string "removals"; then the string "thank-you".

---

But I suspect what you're actually looking for is something a little different, maybe something like:

```
^(?!removals\/)\w+\/[-\w]*thank-you$

bananas/fred-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/fred-no-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/thank-you-with-words-after - no match.
removals/fred-thank-you - no match.
non-removals/fred-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/removals-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/thank-you-supremovalsale - no match.
bananas/fred-sorry - no match.
```

This assumes that the structure is very fixed: to include anything that ends "/blah-blah-thank-you", unless the first word is exactly "removals/". Without knowing the exact specification, though, the first seems the most likely to be helpful.

---

If you're not trying to extract this string from many others, but are just checking a URL to see if it matches this pattern, then you can simplify it a lot:

```
^(?!.*removals).*thank-you

bananas/fred-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/fred-no-thank-you - MATCH.
bananas/thank-you-with-words-after - MATCH.
removals/fred-thank-you - no match.
non-removals/fred-thank-you - no match.
bananas/removals-thank-you - no match.
bananas/thank-you-supremovalsale - no match.
bananas/fred-sorry - no match.
```

This just matches any string that has "thank-you", and not "removals".

Comment: Thanks Dewi, that worked perfectly. The last case was the one i was looking for, but it's great to have had the full explanation above.

Comment: ...did I really answer this question twice, without noticing? On the same day? Within 30 minutes of each other? I'll just quietly facepalm.

Comment: Ha! I thought you were just particularly helpful. Thanks again